# Schedule task in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, task, schedule

I need to perform a task in my database every month. I'm testing the function that will perform this task by performing it every minute (just for testing), but it's not working..
My Kernel.php file is this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            DB::table('users')->update(['quantidade_posts' => 0]);;
        })->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

As i said, this task is not being performed every minute.. I've followed the Laravel Documentation  for Task Scheduling.. Am i missing something ?

Edit:

[image]

As shown in the picture, the task is scheduled, but it's not performing the query. I've changed the query to the exact one that's on the documentation, and it's still not working:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        DB::table('planos')->delete();
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

Comment: This is to setup Laravel's scheduled actions. But if I recall correctly, you should also make sure the server's crontab contains a call to `php artisan schedule:run`. By the way: if you manually run the command (php artisan schedule:run), does it perform the actions you coded?

Answer (score 0):

The right approach will be creating command for your task follow this link to see how laravel command works [click here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands)

after writing a command you can add your command in the kernel file

```
$schedule->command('users:quantidade_posts_update')->cron('* * * * *')->runInBackground();
```

more over you can replace the * * * * * and add your own time [cron link](https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: Right, but is my approach (Laravel's documentation approach) wrong ? If so, why ? And why is it not working ?

Comment: No, i actually don't know what is supervisor.. I've just followed Laravel's documentation and expected it to work

Comment: sorry my bad you need to add  * * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 this command in crontab of your os

Comment: Isn't there a way to make this in a simpler way ? I mean, the documentation states the it is very simple and easy to make a schedule task, from my understanding, it's only necessary to create a function in the Kernel.php file...

Comment: you might be getting error as you have defined DB::table('planos')->delete(); but you need to add name space **use DB;**

Comment: right, i did forgot that, but i just added "use DB" and it still not working... :(